# .svn folder is not getting created whenever i do a checkout

Tags: svn

i tried the following

1. `svnadmin create svn_repos`
2. `svn import my_first_proj file:///c:/svn_repos -m "initial import"`
3. `svn checkout file:///c:/svn_repos`

and the command returned

```
A    svn_repos\trunk
A    svn_repos\trunk\Sample.txt.txt
A    svn_repos\branches
A    svn_repos\branches\my_pers_branch
Checked out revision 1.
```

Yet the `.svn` folder was not created in the checked out folders.
Because of which [I guess], I'm not able to do `svn  copy` or `svn merge`.

Why does this occur?
what is the problem?
is there anything wrong in my commands

Comment: For people who end up on this question and use subversion 1.7 or better, then read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198880/svn-folder-was-in-every-folder-but-now-its-gone because the newer subversion only creates one .svn directory in the root.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're expecting to find that .svn directory inside the my_first_proj directory. Currently, your svn is checked out inside a "svn_repos" directory, relative to the path you typed in the checkout command. What you may want to do is :

```
svn checkout --force file:///c:/svn_repos/ my_first_proj
```

Which checks out a repository inside an existing directory. The usual approach is to checkout to another directory the first time, though.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Subversion might use hidden _svn directories instead of .svn in some situations.

This behavior is switched by the SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK environment variable. See the [Subversion documentation](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/notes/asp-dot-net-hack.txt).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified a path in your checkout so it's defaulted to the basename of the repository itself. In other words it operated as:

```
svn checkout file:///c:/svn_repos ./svn_repos
```

This has had the effect that it has checked out your working copy within the repository directory! If you look in the repository you should find `trunk` and `branches` directories and the rest of the files. It will behave as you expect if instead you do:

```
svnadmin create svn_repos
svn import my_first_proj file:///c:/svn_repos -m "initial import"
svn checkout file:///c:/svn_repos my_working_copy
```

Comment: I never had a problem with that. If you checkout repo "sources" then it creates a "sources" directory in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's not just hidden (they are by default)?

Try running `dir /AH`

Answer (score 1):

What does 'svn status' say?  If .svn is really missing, it will print something like:

```
svn: warning: '.' is not a working copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some more details:

What directory are you in when you perform each command?

It looks to me like you may be checking out your project into the repository itself?

Also, what operating system are you using?