# .svn folder was in every folder but now it's gone

Tags: svn

I have used TortoiseSVN for a long time.
And I started using AnkhSVN yesterday.
and after that hidden ".svn" in every sub-folders are deleted.

I googled it for some time, but I failed to find it.
".svn in every folder" is not necessary anymore?

Thank you.

Comment: This will bite a lot of people in the future as 1.7 is being adopted.

Comment: Definitively surprising. Also I found out with an error and I just couldn't see how to fix it. 8-( Since it was a new checkout, I just rechecked out everything, but that doesn't seem like a good long term solution...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's likely a result of AnkhSVN using SVN 1.7 and Tortoise was not (though the new versions of Tortoise do).

http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng

In 1.7, the .svn directory is no longer in every versioned directory and just in the root

"A key feature of the changes introduced in Subversion 1.7 is the centralization of working copy metadata storage into a single location. Instead of a .svn directory in every directory in the working copy, Subversion 1.7 working copies have just one .svn directory—in the root of the working copy."

Answer (score 6):

This is a [new feature of Subversion 1.7](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng). It changes the way metadata is stored for your working copy, so that only one .svn directory is required, in the top-level folder. You can read more about it in a few places, such as [this blog post](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2011/10/11/top-new-features-in-subversion-1-7-wc-ng-pristines/) or the [TortoiseSVN release notes.](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html#wcformat)